# Remove files with specific extensions by regexp

Tags: command-line, regex, makefile

I have Makefile for compiling LaTeX *.tex file (tex->dvi->ps->pdf). Then I have command clean for removing unnecessary temporary files (dvi, ps...) like this:

```
rm `ls | grep "^${FILENAME}\.(aux|dvi|ps|log)"`
```

but it removes even the *.pdf file, that I need to keep.If I echo the result of the `ls | grep`, i found, it takes all files, whoose extension begins with the first letter of the extension in the regexp, so

```
echo `ls | grep "^${FILENAME}\.[aux|dvi|ps|log]"`

#echoes proj.aux proj.dvi proj.log proj.pdf proj.ps
```

Other files are left unchanged (*.tex)

How do I select only the files with extensions from regexp (and not *.pdf)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This truly seems like a "I have a problem. I used a RegEx. Now I have 2 problems" situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*On the command line*, you should be using a shell glob instead of trying to regex-match the output of `ls`. For example, in bash you could use either a brace expansion

```
rm "$FILENAME".{aux,dvi,log,ps}
```

or (if extended globbing is enabled)

```
rm "$FILENAME".!(tex|pdf)
```

Within a Makefile, you should probably be using the `make` command's own text transformation functions - in the case of GNU make for example you could use `addprefix` e.g.

```
FILENAME = foo

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        @echo rm $(addprefix $(FILENAME),.aux .dvi .log .ps)
```

giving

```
$ make clean
rm foo.aux foo.dvi foo.log foo.ps
```

See [GNU make: Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_8.html#SEC77)

Answer (score 1):

This expression worked: `ls | grep -E ".(aux|dvi|ps|log)"`. You did not use the -E flag, which allows for grep to use extended regular expressions (i.e. allows | to be interpreted as an or operator). Note: you could have also done `ls | grep -E ".aux|dvi|ps|log"` and gotten the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use ls, use find. But anyway here is what you are looking for in the [grep manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
   Matcher Selection
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression  (ERE,  see
          below).
```

so use something like this:

```
echo `find . | grep -E "^${FILENAME}\.(aux|dvi|ps|log)"`
```

Comment: Why is better using find than grep?

Comment: @user1980807 don't use `ls` as pipe input for grep. In a lot of distributions ls is masked with aliases and also colored output. This does't work well with grep and regx.